# How to get the sending intent activity's name?

Tags: android, class, android-intent

I have Aactivity.java and Bactivity.java.

Aactivity sends an Intent that passes the user to Bactivity. 

Intent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Aactivity.this, Bactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I get the name of the Intent sending activity's name (Aactivity in this case) and store it in a String?

**EDIT #1:**

I want to get a string with the activity who sent the intent to Bactivity.

So, if Aactivity sends an Intent to Bactivity, so I want that Bactivity will store a string with the word "Aactivity".

Comment: I'm not perfectly clear about the question.. But why can't you pass the name  as an extra for the intent?

Comment: Because I don't want to check for extra because then, it will check for extra on every intent that I will do and I don't want it.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you cannot use extras? Otherwise the link posted by @MikeM.  is what you're looking for I guess

Comment: read the doc. `getCallingActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the sender activity's name as an extra too.
For example:

```
intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_NAME_BUNDLE_ID", "FancyActivityName");
```

And in the receiver activity's onCreate method handle this extra:

```
String senderActivityName = getIntent().getStringExtra("ACTIVITY_NAME_BUNDLE_ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extra parameter of intent in the Bactivity's onCreate() as

```
String str= getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
boolean bool = getIntent().getExtra("fourthSection" , false);
```

You can send the name of the Activity in the extra of intent by using putExtra but use the same key from every activity from which you calls BActivity...

Comment: It's not very clear. I'm looking for a way to filter the activities without using extra, because then it check this extra for every time the activity will open.

Comment: You can send the name of the Activity in the extra of intent by using putExtra but use the same key from every activity from which you calls BActivity...